# Открывать видео в самом приложении

Tags: java, android, видео

Есть список видюшек, по нажатию на которые хочу открывать видео в браузере.

1. Если правильно понял можно открывать видео прямо в своём приложении, но для этого надо добавлять дополнительные библиотеки. Хотя я и нашёл очень классный вариант [тут](http://createdineden.com/blog/post/android-tutorial-how-to-integrate-youtube-videos-into-your-app/) но нагромождать приложение библиотеками не очень бы хотелось. Поэтому остаётся вариант открывать видео в браузере.
2. Пробую присвоить нажатие по видео:

   ```
   viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://vimeo.com/187799034")));
                   }
               });
           }
   ```

Но на данный момент у меня стоит ссылка по умолчанию, хочу в onClick закинуть метод `onUserInput`, который будет обрабатывать ссылку

```
 private String onUserInput(String input) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(input);
        if (input.contains("youtube")) {
            yotubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/";
            String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(videoID)) {
                String[] str = input.split("/");
                videoID = str[str.length - 1];
                yotubeUrl = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/0.jpg";
                return yotubeUrl;

            } else if (input.contains("vimeo")) {
                playUrl = "https://vimeo.com/";
                String playId;
                String[] str = input.split("/");
                playId = str[str.length - 1];
                playUrl = "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" + vimeoId + "_100x75.jpg";
                return vimeoUrl;
            }
        }
```

и опять же, данный метод преобразовывает ссылку в формат для получения картинки:

```
yotubeUrl = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/0.jpg";
```

Как изменить метод так, чтобы он загружал полученную ссылку в WebView(loadUrl)?

Answer (score 1):

> подскажите как написать метод распознания ссылки, на которую нажали?

Не надо ничего писать, все уже написано до Вас. В методе `void onBindViewHolder (VH holder, int position)` параметр  `position` – это номер элемента `RecyclerView`, по которому Вы можете получить всю информацию о содержании данного элемента.

Comment: я использую gridView

Comment: В адаптере для `GridView` есть метод `public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`. Далее все по аналогии. А вообще, лучше перейти с `GridView` на `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @Inkognito, У Вас есть список видео. Вы хотите при нажатии на какой-либо элемент из этого списка открывать видео из этого элемента в браузере. Каждый такой элемент, в частности, содержит ссылку на видео. В методе `getView(...)` для каждого элемента списка Вы можете создать `OnClickListener`, и, в зависимости от `position` получать ссылку на видео и открывать это видео в браузере.

Comment: это наверное будет работать если у меня список с фиксированными значениями, а у меня он каждый раз меняется..

Comment: Нет, это будет работать в любом случае. У Вас в адаптере есть какое-то множество объектов (данных, которые Вы выводите на экран)? По `position` Вы сможете получить конкретный элемент из этого множества.